# What is the correct SQL query for this?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that stores all the user activities. I call it the "sessions" table with fields:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|  id   |  content_type  |  content_id  |  action  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

content_type can be 1=videos, 2=slideshows, 3=forms, 4=surveys, 5=websites, 6=interactives

content_id is the ID of the actual content. For example I have the "websites" table

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|  id   |   name   |           url            |
+------------------+--------------------------+
|   3   |  Google  |  http://www.google.com/  |
+------------------+--------------------------+
```

On the app, the user visited the google.com website. What will be stored on the "sessions" table is:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|  content_type  |  content_id  |          action          |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|        5       |       3      |  Visited Google Website  |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

These contents of the "websites" (or forms, videos, etc.) table can be attached or tagged to a number of product groups.

I do this by storing it to a table named "attached_product_groups"

on that table, I have the fields:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|  content_type  |  content_id  |  product_group_id  |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

For example I have to attach 3 product groups to the google.com website, from the "product_groups" table:

```
+----------------------------+
|  id  |        name         |
+----------------------------+
|  3   |  Mobile             |
+----------------------------+
|  8   |  Social Networking  |
+----------------------------+
|  9   |  Adsense            |
+----------------------------+
```

"attached_product_groups" table will store:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|  content_type  |  content_id  |  product_group_id  |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|       5        |      3       |         3          |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|       5        |      3       |         8          |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|       5        |      3       |         9          |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Now my question is, how do I select all the "session" logs of a cetain product groups?

Given that on my app, I have a dropdown of the product groups.

Thanks a lot for helping a beginner like me. :)

Answer (score 0):

May be it working below query to displayed the web name and products of the website based on content id

> select  sessions.content_id,web.name,p.name from session
>   sessions,websites web,products p,attached_product_groups pg where
>   sessions.content_id=web. id and p.id=pg.product_group_id

Comment: thank you very much for your response, I'm gonna try this out. :)